# Do not display results till search is executed in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, search-engine

I am trying to display only the results of the search and not the whole database.

here is my controller:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index(string searchString)
    {
        var asset = from s in db.AssetInventoryTables
                    select s;
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
        {
            asset = asset.Where(s => s.AssetTag.Contains(searchString) ||
                    s.ECCNNum.Contains(searchString) ||
                    s.GTag.Contains(searchString) ||
                    s.ItarNum.Contains(searchString) ||
                    s.ViperTag.Contains(searchString) ||
                    s.PartNum.Contains(searchString) ||
                    s.SerialNum.Contains(searchString) ||
                    s.SerialNum2.Contains(searchString) ||
                    s.SerialNum3.Contains(searchString) ||
                    s.SerialNum4.Contains(searchString) ||
                    s.SerialNum5.Contains(searchString) ||
                    s.SchedBCode.Contains(searchString) ||
                    s.Notes.Contains(searchString) ||
                    s.Name.Contains(searchString) ||
                    s.LocationTable.LocNAME.Contains(searchString) ||
                    s.ITARTable.ItarTYPE.Contains(searchString) ||
                    s.ProgramTable.ProgNAME.Contains(searchString) ||
                    s.StatusTable.StatTYPE.Contains(searchString) ||
                    s.SystemTable.SysNAME.Contains(searchString)
                    );
        }
        var assetinventorytables = db.AssetInventoryTables.Include(a => a.ITARTable).Include(a => a.LocationTable).Include(a => a.LocationTable1).Include(a => a.MoveTable).Include(a => a.ProgramTable).Include(a => a.RMATable).Include(a => a.ShipProviderTable).Include(a => a.ShipStatusTable).Include(a => a.SiteLocationTable).Include(a => a.StatusTable).Include(a => a.SystemTable).Include(a => a.TransferTable);
        //return View(await assetinventorytables.ToListAsync());
        return View(asset);
    }
```

I am trying to search multiple fields.
here is my index.cshtml

```
<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Movement2", FormMethod.Get))
{
<p>
        Search: @Html.TextBox("searchString")
        <input type="submit" value="Search" />
    </p>

if ("searchString" != null)
{
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ViperTag)
        </th>
        <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PartNum)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SerialNum)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Notes)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LocationTable.LocNAME)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ProgramTable.ProgNAME)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.StatusTable.StatTYPE)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SystemTable.SysNAME)
    </th>

    <th></th>
</tr>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ViperTag)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PartNum)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SerialNum)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Notes)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LocationTable.LocNAME)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProgramTable.ProgNAME)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.StatusTable.StatTYPE)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SystemTable.SysNAME)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.AssetID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.AssetID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.AssetID })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
}
}
```

here is where i am trying to keep the page from displaying all records when it loads. All i want to see is the search box and once the search box has a value and is submitted then it will only display the results of the search. that is why i am using an IF statement but it still shows all the records on page load. I am stumped.

Comment: first of all what is //if ("searchString" != null)

Comment: Surely whatever layer you've got in front of your database understands the `offest` and `limit` parameters (or implements an equivalent construct)?

Comment: the searchString is the string that the user types into the search box. I dont want the page to display any records until the search is executed so if the searchString value is null then dont execute any more of the code.

Comment: That is possibly the worst `Where()` clause I have ever seen. It will never hit an index as you are doing `Contains` on everything. This will work for small data sets, but when it starts getting much bigger, you'll find this will completely bottleneck and lock out your system.

Answer (score 0):

you need to have TWO action methods

1. with action filter HTTPGET
2. the existing one decorated as  HTTPPOST

the search button should **POST** the data **not** FormMethod.Get

Hide the table when ModelCount is 0